# C# - Cycle through and get values of XML values with same name

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to take some values from an XML document that is laid out like so

```
<Work>
    <Name>Group Work</Name>
    <Data>
        <Day>
            <Attended>7</Attended>
            <StartTime>12:00</StartTime>
            <Date>01-01-2018</Date>
        </Day>
        <Day>
            <Attended>4</Attended>
            <StartTime>11:00</StartTime>
            <Date>02-01-2018</Date>
        </Day>
        <Day>
            <Attended>11</Attended>
            <StartTime>13:00</StartTime>
            <Date>03-01-2018</Date>
        </Day>
    </Data>
</Work>
```

I would like to take each individual day's out data individually.

i.e to take out the number of attendees per session and calculate an average while still displaying the attended number with its respective day.

So far I have managed to take out the first `<Attended>` value with the following code:

```
XmlNode attendedValue = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Work/Data/Day/Attended");
```

But I'm unsure as to how I go about cycling through each `<Day>` and taking its unique value. Is it possible to filter these by the date?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `Linq-to-XML` it's much nicer than the old DOM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml

Comment: Took a look, I think you might be right on that one. Thank you for the helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> dict = doc.Descendants("Work")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Name"), y => y.Descendants("Day")
                    .GroupBy(a => ((DateTime)a.Element("Date")).Add((new TimeSpan(((DateTime)a.Element("StartTime")).Hour,((DateTime)a.Element("StartTime")).Minute,0))), b => (int)b.Element("Attended"))
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

         }
    }

}
```